# PHP : Send email upon checkbox

Tags: php, sql

I’ve got a list where it’s done by a search. I want to send email to the selected person. I’ve done the coding and function but it still doesn’t work out. Please help me out.

**FORM :**

```
<td align="left"><?php echo ucwords(stripslashes($row_list['nama'])); ?>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="txt_email_list" value="<?php echo $row_list['email']; ?>" /></td> 

<td width="300" align="left">Send&nbsp;<a href="send_surat.php"><img src="images/email.png" width="24" height="24" border="0" align="absbottom"></td>
```

**SEND FUNCTION**

```
$subject = 'Detail about u';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maklumat Majikan dan Tarikh Temuduga</title>
</head>
<body>
  //message
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: JobsMalaysia Centre <jmciskandar_m@mohr.gov.my>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: example@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: examplecheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

if(isset($_POST['total_email']) && is_array($_POST['total_email'])){
    foreach($_POST['total_email'] as $to){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
else{
 echo "No email addresses to send to!";
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
<form action="send_surat.php" method="post" name="send_surat" class="search_form">
<td align="left"><?php echo ucwords(stripslashes($row_list['nama'])); ?></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="email"/>
<input type="hidden" name="total_email" id="total_email" value="<?php echo $row_list['email']; ?>"/></td>

<td><input type="submit" name="btn_email" id="btn_email" value="Send Email"/></td>
```

Comment: "It doesn't workout" is extremely unhelpful. Try adding some details.

Comment: You're just linking to the PHP page. You have to submit your form

Comment: The input needs to be wrapped in a form tag. Also, you can't pass a form variable with an anchor tag. Use input type="submit" instead and have it action to send_surat.php.

Comment: @dukedevil294 i'll already did that , but it doesn't work out . The code is on the edit section .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually linking using anchor where data is not passed to the next page

to pass the data and read it using $_POST ... the data should be sent with the header

to do this create a html form
example

for each data you want to pass create an hidden input element like this

when you submit this form
you will find that

$_POST['thisdataname']='thisdatavalue';

---

**EDIT**

WHEN you want the post to be an array 
name of input must end with []

ie. name="total_email[]"

Comment: i'll already do that , but still it say 'no email addresses to send to' .

Comment: use  name="total_email[]"